# Provisioning Windows VM with Vagrant cannot execute remote WinRM commands

Tags: windows, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to install some basic tools on an existing Vagrant box, but my shell commands fail because Vagrant cannot execute WinRM commands.

I get the following output:

```
❯ vagrant up --provider vmware_workstation
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_workstation' provider...
==> default: Cloning VMware VM: 'StefanScherer/windows_2019'. This can take some time...
==> default: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
==> default: Preparing network adapters...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 3389 => 3389. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Starting the VMware VM...
==> default: Waiting for the VM to receive an address...
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: -- 3389 => 2200
    default: -- 5985 => 55985
    default: -- 5986 => 55986
    default: -- 22 => 2222
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
    default: WinRM username: vagrant
    default: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    default: WinRM transport: negotiate
An error occurred executing a remote WinRM command.

Shell: Cmd
Command: hostname
Message: [WSMAN ERROR CODE: 2147942421]: <f:WSManFault Code='2147942421' Machine='127.0.0.1' xmlns:f='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault'><f:Message><f:ProviderFault path='%systemroot%\system32\winrscmd.dll' provider='Shell cmd plugin'>The device is not ready. </f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault>
```

When I have a look at the VM it has the "do you want to trust this network" pop-up open. When I follow the process and accept the prompt the provisioning continues as expected, but I don't really want to stay put waiting for Windows to come up to click a button. Is there a way to automate this?

This is the Vagrantfile I'm using:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "StefanScherer/windows_2019"

  # Setup environment.
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.ps1"
  # PowerShell must be reloaded, so we'll open up a new instance.
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "choco install firefox azure-cli terraform"

  config.vm.provider "vmware_workstation" do |v|
    v.gui = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. After some more testing I discovered that I just had to increase the number of retries for WinRM connections in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.winrm.max_tries = 300 # default is 20
config.winrm.retry_delay = 2 #seconds. This is the defaul value and just here for documentation.
```

This sets the timeout to 10 minutes which on my machine is more than enough to boot up a Windows VM. The default of 40s however is often not enough and would only sometimes provision my VM correctly.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: btw u can accept your own question